# Why the simple bb make python recipe works

Tags: python, yocto, openembedded

I saw a python module bb:

```
DESCRIPTION = "actually, it is not foo"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM="file://PKG-INFO;md5=11223344556"

inherit pypi distutils python3native

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "112233445566"
```

and the bb file name is

```
python-foo_0.8.7.bb
```

I don't understand, why it just works.

There is no SRC_URI, no git, no files, why this bb can install the target pythong module in yocto?

Comment: Take a look at the inherited classes (pypi.bbclass for SRC_URI et al).

Comment: I can't find introduction, do you have any?

Comment: Classes in general are explained in the documentation, pypi.bbclass does not seem to be documented (this is probably an oversight, could be filed as bug) but it can be found in meta/classes/ directory in poky sources.